# How to pass serialized data to hidden html field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Using http://johnny.github.io/jquery-sortable/
(refer to: Connected lists with limited drop targets)

This line:

```
 onDrop: function (item, container, _super) {
   $('#serialize_output').text(group.sortable("serialize").get().join("\n"))
   _super(item, container)
 },
```

Outputs serialized data as:

```
Fourth Item,First Item,Second Item,Third Item
```

Which can be visualized using:

```
<pre id="serialize_output">&nbsp;</pre>
```

I want to output it into `hidden input` field `value field` not as text between `<pre>` and `</pre>`.

Comment: You should put your answer in an answer comment, not in the original question. Answering your own questions is good usage of SO.

Answer (score 0):

Changed .text to .val in

```
 onDrop: function (item, container, _super) {
   $('#serialize_output').val(group.sortable("serialize").get().join("\n"))
   _super(item, container)
 },
```

And added hidden field:

```
 <input id="serialize_output" name="orderin" type="hidden" value="change_here">
```

FIXED.